# All python helper causing mypy to think field is optional

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, optional-parameters

When using the python all() helper I am seeing odd behaviour with mypy (version 0.942) where it thinks a field is optional even though the all() helper would make sure all of them exist.

For the following code snippet I am seeing odd behavior from mypy

```
def rate_limit(user_id: int, rate_limit_max: int, rate_limit_since_time: int):
    do_something()

def some_func(
    user_id: int = None, 
    rate_limit_max: int = None, 
    rate_limit_since_time: int = None
): 
    if all([user_id, rate_limit_max, rate_limit_since_time]):
        rate_limit(user_id, rate_limit_max, rate_limit_since_time)
```

For this code snippet I get something along these lines:

```
error: Argument "user_id" to "rate_limit" has incompatible type "Optional[int]"; expected "int"
```

Comment: `if` is probably special-cased by mypy so that everything inside the `if` uses the result. `all` presumably doesn't have that

Comment: @joel So does this seem like a bug in mypy then? IMO `if all([...])` is cleaner than `if user_id and rate_limit_max and rate_limit_since_time`.

Comment: @ChristopherForsythe no, this isn't a bug. You shouldn't have expected this to work.

Comment: Check out the relevant [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html) note, you can get what you want if you use a type guard.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs juanpa provided above I was able to find ([PEP-647](https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/)) looks like mypy can't figure out what the type returned from the all() helper would be.

From the docs

> There are cases where type narrowing cannot be applied based on static information only. Consider the following example:
>
> ```
> def is_str_list(val: List[object]) -> bool:
>     """Determines whether all objects in the list are strings"""
>     return all(isinstance(x, str) for x in val)
>
> def func1(val: List[object]):
>     if is_str_list(val):
>         print(" ".join(val)) # Error: invalid type
> ```
>
> This code is correct, but a type checker will report a type error because > the value val passed to the join method is understood to be of type List[object]. The type checker does not have enough information to statically verify that the type of val is List[str] at this point.